# How to efficiently select the minimum value in a column grouped by index pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the smallest value per index in python pandas however the data set I am using is quite large. How would I most efficiently accomplish the following:
given a DataFrame:

```
index   col1 col2
i1      1    5
        2    6

i2      3    7
        4    8
```

How would I most efficiently get the smallest value in col1 grouped by index i.e. [1,3] or {'i1':1,'i2':3} etc., The following quite obviously is a sub standard implementation

```
min_time = [frame.loc[index_val]['timestamp_ms'].min() for index_val in ['i1','i2']]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `min`, then convert output to list or dictionary:

```
out = df.groupby(level=0)['col1'].min().tolist()
```

Or:

```
out = df.groupby(level=0)['col1'].min().to_dict()
```

Nicer solution with [`Series.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html):

```
out = df['col1'].min(level=0).tolist()
out = df['col1'].min(level=0).to_dict()
```